# Google Pagespeed lazyload jquery masonry conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, jquery-masonry, pagespeed

On my website a have an inspiration gallery with images positioned with [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Since today I activated the [Google Pagespeed lazyload module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/filter-lazyload-images) on my server, which work as follows according to the documentation:

> The lazyload_images filter defers loading of images until they become
>   visible in the client's viewport or the page's onload event fires.

The gallery items inside the viewport display properly, but outside not:

[image]

The masonry script does not calculate the right height anymore. So does anyone have an idea what I can change to run the script in the right order.

**I run the masonry as follows:**

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    // Window on load
    $( window ).on( 'load', function( e ) {

        // Masonry on inspiration gallery
        $( '#pins_masonry' ).masonry({
            itemSelector: '.pin-masonry'
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: You can try this: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#tip-specifying-image-dimensions-minimizing-reflows-and-avoiding-page-jumps or this: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes#updating-layout-of-js-widgets Here are examples for these techniques: http://codepen.io/aFarkas/pen/VYGvde and http://codepen.io/aFarkas/pen/JdrXjm

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I prefer to use Google pagespeed lazyload if it possible.

Comment: If you would read, what I linked, than you will understand, that you can apply the same thing to your problem. It is a general solution to a general problem. The sections I linked to not even use any lazysizes specific code. You have to either change your CSS or how you update masonry.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas The difference in my opinion is that your examples are kinds where you load the image by data-src and mine is directly with the default src property.

Comment: 1. lazyloading is only possible by not adding the actual image url to the `src` attribute. google pagespeed isn't using a `data-src`, but has the same mechanic. 2. The techniques described are generic solutions: 1. solutions makes sure, that the width and height is calculable by JS before the actual image is loaded and 2. solution re-trigger masonry's layout as soon as an image is loaded. Both solutions work with any kind of masonry image galleries.